# Is a computational scientist/engineer a viable professional goal?

Tags: mathematics, career-path, engineering

One one hand, there were attempts to give some meaning to the term on Wikipedia; there is [a page on SIAM's website](http://www.siam.org/students/resources/report.php) and a [Master's program at Stanford](https://icme.stanford.edu/academics/degree-programs).

On the other hand, there are very few jobs which use the term. However, there are positions with "Computational" and "Engineer" like "Computational Imaging Engineer", "Computational Biology Engineer" and so on.

I assume that skills and knowledge, which are necessary for doing a job with "Computational" in the name are, roughly, the same. Consequently, if a person has a core set of skills and knowledge, it should be easy to apply them in different fields.

Am I right in my assumption, and "computational scientist" is a possible career goal? Or it is too broad a term (e.g., a synonym for "applied mathematician") and should not be considered as a specific goal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Computational science is more of a mode of work than an actual career path—using modeling and mathematical techniques to solve problems in engineering, medicine, finance, and other disciplines. Almost all computational scientists have an area of emphasis within that field (as you mentioned, computational imaging engineer or computational biologist). You can move within areas relatively closely related, but making larger leaps may be more difficult: a computational fluid mechanics expert cannot quickly be substituted for someone working in bioinformatics, and vice versa.

Comment: In what stage of a career development one should start to specialize? Is this "specializing" more about experience or about math involved? In other words, "quickly" is more like a pure mathematician going into cs field, or a statistician going into what is called data science (stats + cs/ml)

Comment: You'd have to specialize beginning as a graduate student. Note that you can still switch later—but it's not the kind of situation you'd want to jump into if you have a tight deadline.

Comment: Can getting into a "mode of work" be a career goal? Lets say that at the moment I am interested at Computer Vision, however I am not so obsessed with the topic that I am not considering any other options. Whereas, I am pretty sure about my interest in mathematical optimization and large scale computing (from a cs point of view).

Comment: Optimization is a major area of computational science. HPC (high-performance computing) is another.

Comment: That’s a different question than the main one. Just “computational scientist” is too broad. But it can be combined with an application domain to provide a career objective—such as computational chemist or materials scientist.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases computation is a tool, not the specialism. Many engineers work primarily through simulations or modelling, as do many oceanographers, physicists, chemists, etc, but in most cases it's not a subject in its own right; the specialist knowledge is in engineering, or physics, or whatever, and the computational side is learned on top of that. (possibly bioinformatics is a bit of an exception here?)

Off the top of my head there are two other routes which are more about the computing side: that of "data scientist", which I guess is the computational form of being a general statistician; and the newly-emerging role of "research software engineer", which focuses on the programming side, usually in order to facilitate other people's research - analogous in some ways to a lab technician. RSE is a concept that is only just beginning to gain traction as a career path, so may not really exist in your country yet.